# Fetching data after a certain time interval(10 sec) from a continuously increasing database like mysql using flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to create an api using python and flask that fetches data in regular time interval(10 sec) from a continuously increasing database where data is continuously coming and stored.I don't want to fetch the old data which were already fetched.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Suppose you are getting data from an iot device or sensor and storing values in a database which is continuously increasing with time.I want to create an api that  will fetch those data one at a time and send it for dashboarding in a regular time interval.

Comment: Adjust your API so it takes a reference (last queried date, primary key) so the server can filter based on that value-- and return only the more recent information.

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution please ? @Doobeh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you currently have an API endpoint that returns all the database stored data:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['post'])
def data():
    all_the_data = Data.query.order_by(Data.created.desc()).all()
    return jsonify(results=all_the_data)
```

So your ajax call currently doing something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/data",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
        update_graph(data);
    }
});
```

You just need a way for the system to filter what's going out, back to the client-- so we instead of querying all the data, we can filter based on a reference:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['post'])
def data():
    client_data = request.json
    reference = client_data.get('reference')

    if reference:
        # we have a reference, so lets filter the query:
        query_data = Data.query.filter(Data.id>reference).order_by(Data.created.desc()).all()
    else:
        # no reference, so send the lot!
        query_data = Data.query.order_by(Data.created.desc()).all()

    return jsonify(results=query_data)
```

Then your ajax request needs to get the last reference from the last query it did-- and supply that to the API endpoint:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/data",
    data: JSON.stringify({ reference: 999 }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data)
       update_graph(data["results"]);
    }
});
```

So you just need to work out how to get that `reference` value from the last set of values you recieved (the API could send that back as another key, or you could poll your current set within javascript, etc).